# Is this Optimus Prime figure based on any canonical instance?

Tags: transformers

Hot Toys has just announced a new Optimus Prime figure, with removable Starscream wings.

I know that in various canons, Optimus has been able to fly utilizing various upgrades, whether temporary or permanent. The most similar instance/design I am personally aware of was

> Optimus utilizing the cannibalized spare parts of Jetfire to temporarily upgrade himself in *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen*

Across the mass of Transformers canons (shows, movies, comics, books, even toys), is there any instance of Optimus attaching Starscream's wings to himself, on which this figure may be even loosely based?

[image: Optimus + Starscream]

Comment: A side note. In the original Transformers, the Autobots could fly as was seen in season one episodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Transformers World, it's apparently an obscure reference to the G1 episode "Megatron's Master Plan", in which Starscream disguised himself as Optimus Prime.

> For those not aware of the Starscream reference, the Generation 1
>   episode "Megatron's Masterplan" showed Decepticons masquerading as
>   Autobots to discredit them, which showed a scene of Starscream as
>   Optimus Prime with wings out.

Here's the page:
http://www.tfw2005.com/transformers-news/generation-1-1/official-hot-toys-g1-optimus-prime-figure-starscream-version-180770/

Comment: Ah, yes. I had forgotten about that episode. Another one of those logic-filled episodes.

Comment: Maybe Op was *[Starscream all along](http://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/1/10/G1toon_starscream_prime_cosplay.jpg)!* Think about it, did you ever see them in the same room together?

Comment: Oh I see! That's brilliant actually. I might have to get that figure. That story arc was one of my favorites.